# What is the diff between apache hadoop and cloudera hadoop

Tags: hadoop, cloudera

Could any one explain me what is the diff between hadoop and cloudera hadoop?

Comment: This question have just simple answer. That is different vendor  and all the other company who are building any software realted to hadoop using apache hadoop as base.

Answer (score -1):

**What Is Apache Hadoop?**

The Apache™ Hadoop® project develops open-source software for reliable, scalable, distributed computing.

The Apache Hadoop software library is a framework that allows for the distributed processing of large data sets across clusters of computers using simple programming models. It is designed to scale up from single servers to thousands of machines, each offering local computation and storage. Rather than rely on hardware to deliver high-availability, the library itself is designed to detect and handle failures at the application layer, so delivering a highly-available service on top of a cluster of computers, each of which may be prone to failures.

**Cloudera** is the leader in Apache Hadoop-based software and services and offers a powerful new data platform that enables enterprises and organizations to look at all their data — structured as well as unstructured — and ask bigger questions for unprecedented insight at the speed of thought.

Cloudera is startup company, They are providing commercial support for hadoop.

Answer (score -1):

here are some of the advantages of Cloudera Hadoop:
1. Cloudera provides a tool SCM that would kind of automatically set up a hadoop cluster for you.

2. Cloudera bundles the hadoop related projects which is pretty ease to install on any standard linux boxes()
3. Cloudera ensures that the CDH release and the available hadoop projects for the release are compatible(for example you don’t have to take the hassle on finding the compatible hbase release with your hadoop release and integration between related projects etc)
4. There are a good number of large enterprises using CDH with cloudera support.(Cloudera provides various support packages)

A detailed explanations can be found [here](http://geekprogrammers.com/question/difference-between-apache-hadoop-and-cloudera-hadoop/):